# Secure boot validation failure loading ext4_x64.efi

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, secure-boot

**My setup:**
- Lenovo U510 with preinstalled Windows 8
- UEFI and Secure Boot enabled
- Fedora 20 installed on a new ESP partition

Having two ESPs I wasn't able to boot Windows with grub, so I switched to rEFInd (I also had to manually sign EFI/refind/grubx64.efi, as described [on Rod Smith's page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#mok))

**Where it all started**
I'd like to use only one ESP partition. While I was looking for a solution to this, I noticed that refind is unable to locate my linux kernels, as it only lists .efi files on both ESPs (that's why I was able to boot both Windows and GRUB).
[Here's my refind.conf](http://pastebin.com/tCT62qWE) (**scan_all_linux_kernels** enabled, also I hope using pastebin is OK)

**What I think the problem is**
There's one issue I had been ignoring the entire time. The first thing I see on boot after **"lenovo"** is an error: `Secure boot validation failure loading ext4_x64.efi!!`, rEFInd comes in next.
Now, all linux kernel images are located on `/boot` partition (ext4), and `.efi` files reside in `/boot/efi/` (ESP partition, fat16).
**Is it possible that when ext4_x64.efi module is not secure booted properly, rEFInd is not able to scan my /boot partition for standalone kernel files?**
Or is this something else I'm missing? How do I get rid of this error?

---

**Additional info:**
**blkid**

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="WINRE_DRV" UUID="8C8AFDF48AFDDB22" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="d9b3d1c6-4303-4bcb-9a8d-520d77eba09c"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="AE00-9C33" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="56df4a86-ccb5-468b-8742-28466aeb8e24"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="LRS_ESP" UUID="D801-2A31" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8ae04a7d-5512-4e56-ad53-e8431f46bb82"
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="Windows8_OS" UUID="94EA0522EA0501EA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7a69ef1a-dbca-4d12-89b2-f18f7f11c874"
/dev/sdb6: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="625A-58E6" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="6eaed3b6-fa5c-44d2-bfc4-343d8ffd2690"
/dev/sdb7: UUID="AE0A19760A193D31" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0fec95d1-aade-4bc6-9026-56677c901e5a"
/dev/sdb8: LABEL="Data" UUID="42DE4F7CDE4F676F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="460a205a-36c0-48c2-826e-64aa3e58f2bf"
/dev/sdb9: LABEL="PBR_DRV" UUID="32460A2F4609F47F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a8675e43-d43a-4ba3-8e05-b2716def2c46"
/dev/sdb10: UUID="86287fa0-d7ea-4518-84b2-6e937a7b25f6" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="FEBOOT" PARTUUID="7920836d-4e52-4947-82da-a6923cac8dda"
/dev/sdb11: UUID="EWxdkJ-1Oik-LHqI-15ae-H3jK-X8Fx-M94zaF" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="92e136b9-1b81-4faa-8ee4-becbd51b0626"
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap: UUID="0689c9f8-a2b3-469b-8660-0c3046edf269" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/fedora-root: UUID="32c195a6-aa8c-4bf9-bf95-d9cd803a4ec5" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/fedora-home: UUID="d6df1f66-725c-4453-a95d-b9e2fe1546e9" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: PARTLABEL="HFS" PARTUUID="4613ee39-4727-4347-8134-173f590f716f"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="fc8c6c49-6548-4b7d-9531-e9f6eada8709"
/dev/sdb4: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="3c33975f-7333-4ea1-b9dc-16e175acb6e1"
```

**parted /dev/sdb print**

```
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1050MB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      1050MB  1322MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, hidden
 3      1322MB  2371MB  1049MB  fat32        Basic data partition          hidden
 4      2371MB  2505MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 5      2505MB  318GB   316GB   ntfs         Basic data partition
 6      318GB   318GB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition          boot
10      318GB   319GB   524MB   ext4         FEBOOT
11      319GB   489GB   170GB                                              lvm
 7      489GB   490GB   367MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 8      490GB   979GB   489GB   ntfs         Basic data partition
 9      979GB   1000GB  21.5GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

**efibootmgr -v**

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0007,0005,0003,0006,0000,2001
Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System        HD(3,276800,1f4000,8ae04a7d-5512-4e56-ad53-e8431f46bb82)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (B8-88-E3-93-8D-81)      ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(b888e3938d81,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (B8-88-E3-93-8D-81)    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(b888e3938d81,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000RC
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,56df4a86-ccb5-468b-8742-28466aeb8e24)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0004* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(6,2507d000,64000,6eaed3b6-fa5c-44d2-bfc4-343d8ffd2690)File(\EFI\refind\shim.efi)
Boot0005* Fedora        HD(6,2507d000,64000,6eaed3b6-fa5c-44d2-bfc4-343d8ffd2690)File(\EFI\fedora\shim.efi)
Boot0006* EFI HDD Device (ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB)       ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(6,2507d000,64000,6eaed3b6-fa5c-44d2-bfc4-343d8ffd2690)RC
Boot0007* Fedora        ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(6,2507d000,64000,6eaed3b6-fa5c-44d2-bfc4-343d8ffd2690)File(\EFI\fedora\shim.efi)..
Boot2001* EFI USB Device        RC
```

**EDIT:**
**fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=86287fa0-d7ea-4518-84b2-6e937a7b25f6 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=625A-58E6          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/fedora-home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb8       /media/entertainment    ntfs-3g rw,auto,user,fmask=0111,dmask=0000,noatime,nodriatime 0 0
```

**Also**
`sdb2` is windows ESP (`SYSTEM_DRV`)
`sdb6` is linux ESP  (`/boot/EFI`)
`sdb10` is `/boot` partition (I gave it a name `FEBOOT`)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I've managed to fix the problem.

> Is it possible that when ext4_x64.efi module is not secure booted
>   properly, rEFInd is not able to scan my /boot partition for standalone
>   kernel files?

That was the problem. I signed ext4_x64.efi using tips from [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html#mok) and now everything works fine. I was able to completely remove grub and boot vmlinuz files from the /boot partition with refind.